# Purr::map_df - how to not abort when error occurs?

Tags: r, purrr

I work in R and use map_df to loop throu applications with a function that extracts data.

I loop throu around 750 applications and for a majority of applications it works. But sometimes R throws an error (incorrect number of dimensions), and the loop aborts.

I wonder if there is a way to modify my code so the loop dosen't abort when such an error occurs? I would like to just move on and continue to build the dataset with the applications that works.

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)
library(tesseract)
library(reshape2)

#Function to read data from pdf application

fyh_pdf <- function(pdf) {
  pdf <- pdftools::pdf_text(pdf)
  
  string <- paste0(pdf, collapse = "")
  
  steg1 <- str_extract_all(string, 
                           regex("(?<=Arbetslivets medverkan i utbildningens planering och genomförande).+?(?=Organisation och ledning av utbildningen)", 
                                 dotall = TRUE,ignore_case = TRUE))[[1]]
  
  steg2 <- str_match_all(steg1, regex("Organisationsnamn: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?Insatt: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?Medverkan planering: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?Uppskattat anställningsbehov: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?Andra rekryteringsvägar: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?LIA-platser: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?Medfinansiering: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n.*?Status: *([^\\r\\n]+?)\\r\\n",
                                      dotall=T))[[1]][,-1] 
  
  df <- tibble(utbildning_namn = str_extract(string, regex("(?<=Utbildningens namn:\r\n).*")),
               utbildning_anordnare = str_extract(string, regex("(?<=Ansvarig utbildningsanordnare:\r\n).*")),
               ansökningsnummer = str_extract(string, regex("(?<=Ansökningsnummer:\r\n).*")),
               organisationsnamn=steg2[,1], insatt=steg2[,2], medverkan_planering=steg2[,3], uppskattat_anställningsbehov=steg2[,4],
               andra_rekryteringsvägar=steg2[,5], LIA_platser=steg2[,6], medfinansiering=steg2[,7], status=steg2[,8]) %>% 
    mutate(utbildning_namn = str_trim(utbildning_namn, side = "left"),
           utbildning_anordnare = str_trim(utbildning_anordnare, side = "left"),
           ansökningsnummer = str_trim(ansökningsnummer, side = "left"))
  
  return(df)
}

#Let's loop!

setwd("H:/R/YH_ANSÖKNINGAR/YH_2018/")
filenames <- list.files(path = "H:/R/YH_ANSÖKNINGAR/YH_2018/") %>% 
  str_subset(pattern="_Ans_")


df <- map_df(.x = filenames, ~fyh_pdf(pdf = .x))
```

Comment: Have a look at `purrr::safely` or `purrr::possibly`.

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example of `purrr::safely` in action. Please provide a reproducible example if you need further assistance.

```r
library(purrr)

min5 <- function(x) {
  x - 5
}

df <- list(a = c(2,3,5,6),
     b = c('a','b'), # non numeric to cause error
     c = c(9,10,11,21))


map(df,min5) # doesnt run
#> Error in x - 5: non-numeric argument to binary operator

map(df,safely(min5))
#> $a
#> $a$result
#> [1] -3 -2  0  1
#> 
#> $a$error
#> NULL
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$result
#> NULL
#> 
#> $b$error
#> <simpleError in x - 5: non-numeric argument to binary operator>
#> 
#> 
#> $c
#> $c$result
#> [1]  4  5  6 16
#> 
#> $c$error
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>